# Detect when saveAs dialog is canceled

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Following the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download

```
var options = {
  filename: 'dummyName.txt',
  url: 'https://some.url',
  conflictAction: 'uniquify',
  saveAs: true
};
var downloading = browser.downloads.download(options, function() {
  console.log('In callback');
});

console.log(downloading);
downloading.then(function() {
  console.log('started');
}, function() {
  console.log('failed');
});
```

In console, I see ..

```
undefined
downloading is undefined
In callback
Unchecked lastError value: Error: Download canceled by the user
```

How can I prevent the code inside `downloading.then` from running if user canceled the save on dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually simple. Just drop the function() part from the download function, like this:

```
var options = {
    filename: 'dummyName.txt',
    url: 'https://some.url',
    conflictAction: 'uniquify',
    saveAs: true
};
var downloading = browser.downloads.download(options);

console.log("downloading object is " + downloading);

downloading.then(function(id) {
    console.log('started' + id);
}, function(error) {
    if(error.message == "Download canceled by the user"){
        // Do something
        console.log("not going into the success callback..");
    }else{
        console.log('failed' + error);
    }
});
```

You mixed up the callback syntax (which the function() you included does in the download call) and the Promise-based syntax (then()).

If you want to catch errors properly, it's always best to use the Promise-based syntax for developing Firefox addons.

Please note that you can simplify this

```
var downloading = browser.downloads.download(options);
downloading.then(onSuccess, onError);
```

to

```
browser.downloads.download(options).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

Good luck developing Firefox addons!